# How do I hide an URL from browser history

Tags: http-headers, browser-history

Is there any http header or something to prevent the page to be saved on the browser history?

Facts:
I'm not going to use:

window.location.replace(URL);

POST instead of GET;

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178715/dont-save-url-in-history-any-header-or-meta-tag. Take a look at the answers. (Spoiler: Ajax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Browser history is 100% controlled by the browser's settings, and roughly guided by caching "rules" in HTTP.

In a nutshell, most browsers will do the following:

1. All GET requests will be stored in the browser history
2. All POST request URLs will be stored in the browser history (POST *data* will *not*)
3. AJAX requests for URLs *probably* won't be stored in the browser history, but some may